# Servlet/filter specific exception handling in java

Tags: java, servlets, exception, servlet-filters

I have a servlet extending `HttpServlet` and implementing a `GET` request. I also use a filter (from an external library) which is mapped to the above servlet url. Now an exception is thrown by the filter, and as expected I get this

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myServlet] in context with
>   path [] threw exception

I know `error-page` description is probably a standard way to catch this exception, but is there a way to catch the exception from a specific servlet filter ? I already have an `error-page` description and redirecting to a simple html page. I also don't want to redirect to a jsp page or so, and play around with error parameters. In short, my questions are :

- Is there a simpler, elegant way to catch an exception for a *specific* servlet and handle them ? The `error-page` descriptor doesn't seem to have any fields to choose the servlet which throws an exception.
- Is it possible to catch an exception occuring inside a *specific* filter and handle them, given that the exception thrown by the filter is not a custom exception ?

Comment: Is that a checked or unchecked exception?

Comment: The exception is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, the cause of which is known, an invalid input from user. This is documented in the filter documentation, and does this classify as checked exception ? Thing is, it could as well be `NullPointerException', and I want to be able to catch it _knowing_ that it comes from the _specific_ filter.

Comment: That exception is unchecked then. But if this filter is yours, why don't you fix it in the filter itself? If you know it can be thrown and that you should return 401 in this case, just do so instead of letting the exception loose

Comment: Filter is not mine, as said in the question, I use an external library.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that part correctly... Maybe insert a filter before this one to check for input correctness? But it looks like a bug in the other filter

Comment: Thanks. That is possible, but not a straightforward solution. That also means an unnecessary interception in each and every request from user. Besides, if there are more exceptions in this library, I would end up with a second bloated filter checking for all possible scenarios to handle exceptions. What I'm looking for is a simpler solution, wherein I can specify (say as a field of `error-page`) which servlet's exception I'm handling. There doesn't seem to be one though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not extend the Filter and handle the exception thrown by super?

```
public class MyFilter extends CustomFilter{

        private static final Map<String, String> exceptionMap = new HashMap<>();

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
              super.init(config);
              exceptionMap.put("/requestURL", "/redirectURL");
              exceptionMap.put("/someOtherrequestURL", "/someOtherredirectURL");
        }
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           try{
                   super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
              }catch(Exception e)
                    //log
                    String errURL = exceptionMap.get(request.getRequestURI());
                    if(errURL != null){
                        response.sendRedirect(errURL);
                    }
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. This might be possible. Only thing is that, I have a handful of servlets using the same filter, so with this solution I would need to add additional code to identify the `servlet_name` etc. and take action for each. Was wondering if there are any simpler solutions, where I can specify which servlet I'm handling the exception for.

Comment: It has not reached the Servlet yet, so its just an url that points to a Servlet (and which would have accessed the Servlet if the exception hadn't happened). You could maintain a map of such servlet urls and look it up for exception processing. I will edit my code to show what I am talking about,

Comment: Okay. It probably can't get easier than the above, unless it's brought as a feature or so. :) 
Thanks again!