# How to handle AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException of Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, spring-rest

I'm developing a web service project with Spring MVC, Spring Rest, Spring Security and Hibernate in which i have implemented token based authentication using JWT(JSON Web Tokens). 
The problem now is, the token expires in 5 minutes, after that when the user uses the same token it throws the following exception.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.careapple.webservice.security.controller.ProtectedController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c897c03.getDaHoney(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.careapple.webservice.security.filter.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my AuthenticationTokenFilter class;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.careapple.webservice.security.TokenUtils;
import com.careapple.webservice.util.AppConstant;

public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
             throws IOException, ServletException{

        tokenUtils = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(TokenUtils.class);
        userDetailsService = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(UserDetailsService.class);

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, " + AppConstant.tokenHeader);


        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(AppConstant.tokenHeader);
        System.out.println("Token: " + authToken);
        String username = this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            System.out.println("inside first if");
            if (this.tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now, i want to handle that exception so that, i can send a better response like "Token has expired, please login again". Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: you can use @ExceptionHandler for AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

Comment: The exception is thrown in the AuthenticationTokenFilter, it is not reaching the controller.

Comment: You can try it <error-page>
    <exception-type>
          org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException
    </exception-type >
    <location>{your path here}</location>
</error-page> in your web.xml and try sending the response from that url

Comment: There will be no view pages, its's a Rest based webservice.

Comment: Thar's wha I/ve said, return a string cntaining the message from that path

Comment: I followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring to solve the problem, but i didn't put an entry for CorsFilter as the link suggests. I'm only having a AuthenticationTokenFilter entry.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, Obi Wan - PallavJha