# Why can't global exception handling handle exceptions thrown in the filter?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Why can't global exception handling handle exceptions thrown in the filter?

My code is looking like this at the moment:

1. Filter method

   ```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest   httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader("token");
        if (token==null)
            throw new NoTokenException();

        try {
            String s = jwtToken.parseJwt(token);
            httpServletRequest.setAttribute("id",s);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }
   ```
2. Controller advice class

   ```
    @RestControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandle {

        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public void Handle(Exception e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("msg");
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`@RestControllerAdvice` does not work for filters. For them, you need to implement an additional filter as depicted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34633687/16572295.