# How do I catch exceptions in JwtAuthFilter and handle with Global Error Handler in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

As the title states, I am exploring validating recieved jwts as part of a request but I am struggling to figure out how to catch related exceptions thrown in my JWT auth filter and handle them with a global error handler as I appreciate the formatting there.

So far I've tried catching the exceptions in the jwt auth filter and jwt service without the error handler being able to pick them up and have come to realize it seems the handler wont because the filter is a seperate layer from the controllers and services which is where the error handler finds exceptions. I've tried incorporating what I have been able to find on stack overflow and video tutorials so far but without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if you can point me to a visible example so I can see how it is done properly and specifically. Please let me know if I have not provided enough information. The following are what I believe are the relevant classes in their latest state(SecurityConfig, JwtAuthFilter, JwtService, GlobalErrorHandler ). Please forgive the mess as I have been all over the place the last two weeks trying to find something that works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter authFilter;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final UserAuthenticationEntryPoint userAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("filter chain");
            return
                    http
                            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(userAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                            .and()
                            .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                            .csrf().disable()

//                whitelisted
                            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/menu/**", "/api/order/**", "/api/owners-tools/login").permitAll()
                            .and()
//               restricted
                            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/owners-tools/**")
                            .authenticated().and()
                            .sessionManagement()
                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                            .and()
                            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
//                            .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config)throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthFilter**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final OwnerRepository ownerRepository;



    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NotNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


try {
            String authHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            String token = null;
            String username = null;
            Date expiration = null;
            Date issuedAt = null;
//        String passwrd = null;
//        System.out.println(authHeader);
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = authHeader.substring(7);
//            System.out.println("token = " + token);
                username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
//            System.out.println("username = " + username);
                expiration = jwtService.extractExpiration(token);
                System.out.println("expiration = " + expiration);
                issuedAt = jwtService.extractIssuedAt(token);
                System.out.println("issued at = " + issuedAt);
            }

        assert expiration != null;
        if (!issuedAt.before(expiration)){
            throw new JwtException("invalid date") ;
        }
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                System.out.println("encypted username: " + username);
                System.out.println("decrypted : " + jwtService.decrypt(username));
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(jwtService.decrypt(username));
                if (userDetails == null) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user");
                }
                System.out.println("token valid: " + jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails));
                //           UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
                jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null
                        , userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                System.out.println("jwt filter");
//                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
//        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException e){
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"token issued after expiration\" }");
//    response.getOutputStream().println("{error:" +  e.getMessage()  + "}");
    response.getOutputStream().println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
//            throw new ExpiredJwtException(e.getHeader(), e.getClaims(), "expired" );
//    ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper().fail().msg(e.getMessage());
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
//            throws ServletException, IOException {
//        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
//        String token = null;
//        String username = null;
////        String passwrd = null;
////        System.out.println(authHeader);
//        if (authHeader!=null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
//            token = authHeader.substring(7);
////            System.out.println("token = " + token);
//            username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
////            System.out.println("username = " + username);
//        }
//        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
//            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(jwtService.decrypt(username));
//            if (userDetails == null){
//                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user");
//            }
//            //           UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
//            jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails);
//            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null
//                    , userDetails.getAuthorities());
//            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
//            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
//            System.out.println("jwt filter");
//        }
//        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
//    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> ownerRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username invalid."));
    }
}
```

**JwtService**

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    //create token
    @Value("${key}")
    private String SECRET;

    @Value("${BEGIN_KEY}")
    private int BEGIN_KEY;
    @Value("${END_KEY}")
    private int END_KEY;

    @Value("${charmin}")
    private int charmin;

    @Value("${charmax}")
    private int charmax;

    @Value("${submin}")
    private int submin;

    @Value("${submax}")
    private int submax;

    @Value("${ex1}")
    private int ex1;
    @Value("${ex2}")
    private int ex2;
    @Value("${ex3}")
    private int ex3;

    @Value("${CHARSET}")
    private String CHARSET;

    private Key getSignKey(){
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
    private String buildToken(String username){
//        set time variable instead of creating new
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
//                16 hours, reflective of our owners work day - to be altered to facilitate mitigation of token capture
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60) * 16))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println("token issued: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        System.out.println("token expires: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60) * 16));
//        try {
//            return token;
//        }catch (io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException exception){
//            System.out.println(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
//        }
        return token;
    }


    public String generateToken(String username){
        return buildToken(username);
    }

//    validate token

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
//        try {
//            return
//                    Jwts
//                            .parserBuilder()
//                            .setSigningKey(getSignKey())
//                            .build()
//                            .parseClaimsJws(token)
//                            .getBody();
//        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
//            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
//            throw new JwtException("bad jwt");
//        }
        return
                Jwts
                        .parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(getSignKey())
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(token)
                        .getBody();
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    public String extractUsername(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }
    public Date extractIssuedAt(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getIssuedAt);
    }
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token){
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

//    possibly condense into one
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = decrypt(extractUsername(token));
//        if (!username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && isTokenExpired(token)){
//            throw new SignatureException("token no good");
//        }
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

//    public void validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails){
//        final String username = extractUsername(token);
//        userDetails.getUsername();
//    }

    public void validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails){
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        userDetails.getUsername();
    }

//  encrypt - used during development as a means to encrypt credentials
//  before storing them and facilitating decryption means

    public String encrypt(String string){
//        rework

        System.out.println("value to be encrypted: " + string);

        byte[] codeBytes = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        List<Integer> rolledCodeBytes = new ArrayList<>();
        int codeByteValue;
//        System.out.println("begin key: " + BEGIN_KEY);
//        System.out.println("code bytes " + Arrays.toString(codeBytes));
        for (byte codeByte : codeBytes) {
            codeByteValue = codeByte;
//            System.out.println(codeByteValue += BEGIN_KEY);
//            System.out.println("key " + BEGIN_KEY);
            codeByteValue += BEGIN_KEY;
            rolledCodeBytes.add(codeByteValue);
        }
//        System.out.println("rolled code bytes: " + rolledCodeBytes);
//      new collection with altered char values
        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int integer : rolledCodeBytes) {
            chars.add((char) integer);
        }
//      convert chars to string
//        StringBuilder rolledCharBuilder = new StringBuilder(chars.size());
//        for (Character ch : chars) {
//            rolledCharBuilder.append(ch);
//        }
//        System.out.println("chars: " + chars);
//        System.out.println("rolled charbuilder: " + rolledCharBuilder);
//      for each element insert three new random chars
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
            chars.add(i, randomChar());
            i++;
            chars.add(i, randomChar());
            i++;
            chars.add(i, randomChar());
            i++;
        }
        chars.add(randomChar());
        chars.add(randomChar());
        chars.add(randomChar());
//        -----------------------------------
        StringBuilder encryptionBuilder = new StringBuilder(chars.size());
        for (Character ch : chars) {
            encryptionBuilder.append(ch);
        }
        System.out.println("value encrypted: " + encryptionBuilder);
        return encryptionBuilder.toString();
    }

//    decrypt
    public String decrypt(String  encodedString)  {
        String decodedStart = String.valueOf(encodedString.charAt(BEGIN_KEY));
        String decodedEnd = String.valueOf(encodedString.charAt(encodedString.length() - END_KEY));
        String wholeDecoded = "";
        StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = BEGIN_KEY; i < encodedString.length(); i = i + END_KEY) {
            decoded.append(encodedString.charAt(i));
        }
        decoded = new StringBuilder(decoded.substring(submin, decoded.toString().length() - submax));
        wholeDecoded = wholeDecoded.concat(decodedStart + decoded + decodedEnd);
        byte[] decodedBytes = wholeDecoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int decodeByteValue;
        List<Character> decodedChars = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder decrypt = new StringBuilder(0);
        for (byte codeByte : decodedBytes) {
            decodeByteValue = codeByte;
            decodeByteValue -= BEGIN_KEY;
            decodedChars.add((char) decodeByteValue);
        }
        for (Character ch : decodedChars) {
            decrypt.append(ch);
        }
        return decrypt.toString();
    }

    private char randomChar() {
        int min = charmin, max = charmax;
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min)) + min);
        int[] excluded = {ex1, ex2, ex3};
        char choice = 0;
        for (int ex : excluded) {
            choice = random == ex ? randomChar() : (char) random;
        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

**GlobalErrorHandler**

```
@Data
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler{

    private String message;

    private enum LogStatus{
        STACK_TRACE, MESSAGE_ONLY
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Map <String, Object> handleNumberFormatException(
            NumberFormatException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, webRequest);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public Map <String, Object> handleEntityNotFoundException(
            EntityNotFoundException e, WebRequest webRequest) {
        return createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Map <String, Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(
            IllegalArgumentException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, Object> handleUsernameNotFoundException(
            UsernameNotFoundException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return  createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SignatureException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, Object> handleSignatureException(
            SignatureException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return  createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JwtException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, Object> handleJwtException(
            JwtException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return  createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MalformedJwtException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, Object> handleMalformedJwtException(
            MalformedJwtException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return  createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ExpiredJwtException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, Object> handleExpiredJwtException(
            ExpiredJwtException e, WebRequest webRequest){
        return  createExceptionMessage(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, webRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    public Map<String, Object> handleBadCredentialsException(
            BadCredentialsException e, WebRequest webRequest
    ){
        return createExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, webRequest);
    }





//    ---------------- Being reworked


// alter to not just create the message but also log the error
// create method to log the error to an internal file
    private Map<String,Object> createExceptionMessage(String e, HttpStatus status, WebRequest webRequest) {

    Map <String, Object> error = new HashMap<>();
    String timestamp = ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);

    if(webRequest instanceof ServletWebRequest){
        error.put("uri",
                ((ServletWebRequest)webRequest).getRequest().getRequestURI());
    }
    error.put("message", e);
    error.put("status code", status.value());
    error.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    error.put("reason", status.getReasonPhrase());
    return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: please do not link to code and instead include the relevant code into your question. Second Spring Security already has built in handling for JWTs and had such since 2017. Why implement something that already exists? and what is the point of even including a security framework if you dont intend to use its features? and lastly, read the official spring security architecture chapter that explains how exceptions are handled in spring security. If you use the built in features you wont need to implement any exception handling as this is already done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Toerktumlare - Thank you for the suggestions, had not yet worked with stack overflows code formatting.  Perhaps because I am new at this and don't yet have a full grasp of what is already in place? Or because I want a custom response that matches my other error handler as stated in the post? Either way, can you provide a link to the official spring security architecture chapter as so far I have been unable to locate a useable example to work from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: please in the future, if someone tells you to read up on something. Do a google search for it. I searched for "Spring Security Architecture chapter" and it was the first hit. Im sorry, im here to help you and point you in the correct direction. Not putting any effort in, not even using google, is very rude against me. I have told you what you should do. I gave you help, how you take that help is up to you. Im leaving now have a nice day.

Comment: Well isn't that just precious? Someone thinks they're God's gift to fledgling developers and is seeking validation like a moody 20-year-old manager at Mcdonald's.   Please see below for an example of a helpful answer by Nicolas. Just enough code for an observable example and a link provided in order to learn more. Polite, with no condescension or ego involved.  Probably took less than 5 min and wasted non of my time. A truly selfless act and I would look into anything they suggested and offer to help them in any way I can. Don't let the doorknob hit ya where the good lord split ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your global error handler wont catch exceptions thrown at filter level.
You can inject a HandlerExceptionResolver into your filter, and then in case of an exception use the resolveException method.
There's a similar question here [How to manage exceptions thrown in filters in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring).

The second answer is the one I think youre looking for (reusing the GlobalExceptionHandler annotated with @RestControllerAdvice).

And here's an example:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final OwnerRepository ownerRepository;
    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

 @Override
 protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, @NotNullHttpServletResponse response,
                                @NotNull FilterChain filterChain)
                                throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
       //logic
    } catch (Exception e){
       resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
    }
 }
```

Hope that works

Comment: Thank you so much Nicolas for an actually helpful answer. You are a champion of this community!

Comment: Got the result I was looking for. HandlerException resolver looks like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
@NonNull
private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;
```

In order to get @Qualifier to work I created a file called lombok.config in root (ie. src) and added the following lines 
```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier

config.stopBubbling = true
```

Hope this is helpful for someone else. And again thank you @Nicolas Francisco Corvi for that little bit extra kindness and help.

Answer (score 0):

**First create a custom exception handler class and write custom exception method**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler  {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ExpiredJwtException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExpiredJwtException(ExpiredJwtException ex, WebRequest request) {
        // Custom error message class
       var errMsg = new ErrorMessage("error", "Token provided is expired");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errMsg, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Add logic under this filter

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // @Autowired others Bean If required
     
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // Put your JWT filter codes under try catch block
            // Given an example
            final var jwt = jwtService.resolveToken(request);

        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            // Catch exception as you like
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Try with this if you have any problem let me know. Since it is working on my code.