# How to redirect exception to the user(browser) from filter?

Tags: java, spring, jwt, spring-rest

I have a problem with exception handling in Spring Rest application + JWT. I know how to handle exceptions in controllers in oder to send them to user(browser). But how I can redirect exceptions from filter to user if it occurs?

DETAILS ABOUT MY PROBLEM:
Recently I started learning authentication with JWT. Everything is OK while token is valid and not expired. But when the expiration time finishes, I receive my custom exeption with message "Token is expired or invalid!" in run console. While I want to send it to user(browser). Maybe someone knows how to solve this?

Filter:

@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Autowired
public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(request);

    if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)){
        Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);

        if(authentication != null){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
}
```

}

JwtProvider (here I check token validity):

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

```
@Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
private String secret;
@Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
private long validityTimeInMillis;

private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public JwtTokenProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@PostConstruct
protected void init(){
    secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
}

public String createToken(String email, User.Role role){
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(email)
            .claim("role", role)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration((new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + validityTimeInMillis)))
            .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
            .compact();
}

private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}

public Authentication getAuthentication(String token){
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getEmail(token));
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
}

public String getEmail(String token){
    return extractAllClaims(token).getSubject();
}

public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if(bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer_")){
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    try{
        Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);

        if(claims.getExpiration().getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e){
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid!");
    }
}

private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
    return Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

}

I've tried to send error through response afrer catching it in filter and many other silly things (which did not help) =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way would be to use @ResponseStatus
something like this

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "JWT token is expired or invalid!")
public class JwtAuthenticationException extends RuntimeException {
}
```