# circular dependency in spring filters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, circular-dependency, spring-filter

I am trying to catch exception in my custom filter, using `HandlerExceptionResolver`, which forms circular dependecy:

*JwtAuthFilter.java*:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = null;
        String token = null;

        try {
            String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = authHeader.substring(7);
                username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
            }
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails.getUsername())) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

getting error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  jwtAuthFilter (field private org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver com.example.j4.filter.JwtAuthFilter.resolver)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  securityConfig (field private com.example.j4.filter.JwtAuthFilter com.example.j4.security.SecurityConfig.authFilter)
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

I need to put `@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")`, otherwise there are 2 implementations:

```
Field resolver in com.example.j4.filter.JwtAuthFilter required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - errorAttributes: defined by method 'errorAttributes' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
    - handlerExceptionResolver: defined by method 'handlerExceptionResolver' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]
```

Comment: Try to make an additional filter instead of mixing the JWTFilter with the ExceptionHandlerFilter.