# Exception not throwed to global api error handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I defined class for global api error handler in spring boot 3.2.0. I added security with bearer token, I expect to return response but it says 14:41:32.831 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-11150-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

I write global api error handler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ApiGlobalErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiGlobalErrorHandler.class.getName());

    @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedAccessException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @ResponseBody
    protected ApiResponseWrapper handleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
        LOG.error("UnauthorizedAccessException occurred:{},code-{}", ex.getErrorType(), ex.getErrorType().getCode());
        return new ApiResponseWrapper(new ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value() + "." + API_ID_CODE + "." + ex.getErrorType().getCode(), ex.getErrorType().getMessagge()));
    }
```

I expected the error response but I got 14:41:32.831 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-11150-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]. how to disable processing error page?
Trying without bearer token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE3bs.png)
stack trace is:

```
14:41:32.831 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-11150-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
rs.yettel.roamingbarring.exception.UnauthorizedAccessException: Missing Authorization header
    at rs.yettel.roamingbarring.security.ApiKeyAuthFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(ApiKeyAuthFilter.java:19)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:362)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Spring Security version 6.0, the framework began filtering all dispatcher types, such as `request`, `async`, `error`, `forward`, and `include`.

If you want to exclude the `error` dispatcher type in your scenario, you can configure the filter chain as shown below:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

For additional information on this topic, refer to the Spring Security documentation at this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#switch-filter-all-dispatcher-types.

It appears that your `ApiKeyAuthFilter` is raising an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. It's important to note that exceptions thrown within Filters cannot be handled using `@ControllerAdvice`. To gain insights into customizing exceptions thrown within Filters, you may refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring) for guidance.

**EDIT**

After reviewing your code, I have several points to highlight:

1. As mentioned earlier, exceptions raised in the filters are not handled by your `@ControllerAdvice`. To send a custom error message, it is recommended to catch the error within the filter and send the error code using `HttpServletResponse`. I have provided a sample repository demonstrating how to achieve this, which you can find here: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/stackoverflow/tree/spring_security_filter_error_handler_77635124/security).
2. I noticed that you are using `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` in your case. However, if you are only overriding the abstract methods and those methods do not have access to `HttpServletResponse`, you won't be able to send a custom error code and/or message using this approach. In the sample repository I created, you can observe the use of `CustomSecurityFilter`, which extends `OncePerRequestFilter` and is added before running `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. This approach is considered a cleaner way to achieve the desired functionality.

For further customization, I recommend exploring the `BasicErrorController` and `DefaultErrorAttributes` classes in the Spring framework. Additionally, you can refer to the Spring Boot official documentation for more information: [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.0/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling).

Comment: my security code is bellow.

Comment: `.public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    private final String principalRequestHeader;
    public ApiKeyAuthFilter(String principalRequestHeader) {
        this.principalRequestHeader = principalRequestHeader;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return "N/A";
    }
}`

Comment: ` httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).
                authorizeRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/roaming-barring/**").permitAll())
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)).addFilter(whitelistedTokensFilter);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }`

Comment: I am sorry for bad format, I am new on the forum.

Comment: @DobrosavVlaskovic please edit the answer, so that I can have a better picture

Comment: @DobrosavVlaskovic if possible please push sample code to GitHub and share the link here, so that I can take a look

Comment: it not possible that's company's code. I solved that with downgrading version of spring boot. Thank you!

Comment: @DobrosavVlaskovic if you can create a sample application out of it and share that, I can have a look

Comment: I created app, https://github.com/Dobrosav/Spring-Security-problem thank you very much

Comment: I am very interested where is problem

Comment: @DobrosavVlaskovic updated answer after looking into your code, please check

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: **server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false** in your properties file?

Comment: Yes I tried. Not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).