Why is ServletException not captured by /error controller?
Using spring boot 3.3.2
I have an auth filter that extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, which itself extends GenericFilterBean.
When my filter throws a ServletException, because it didn't like what it found in the request, my custom /error page is not being used.  I get the stack trace from Tomcat itself.  Obviously, I want something "pretty" to show the end user.
It seems as though the filter is not aware of being within the context of Spring.  What am I missing here?

In other scenarios, where this particular filter does not throw an exception, the error page presents itself as expected.

application.properties
spring.application.name=Pre Auth Filter

logging.level.org.example=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.debugEnabled=true
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true
spring.codec.log-request-details=true

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration

validReferers={'http://site1.example.com','http://site2.example.com'}

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.path=/error

SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Value("#{${validReferers}}")
  private List<String> validReferers;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService( new CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService() );
    return provider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
    return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
  }


  public CustomPreAuthFilter customPreAuthFilter( AuthenticationManager authenticationManager ) {
    CustomPreAuthFilter customPreAuthFilter = new CustomPreAuthFilter( validReferers );
    customPreAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager( authenticationManager );
    customPreAuthFilter.setPrincipalRequestParam( "email" );
    customPreAuthFilter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource( new CustomPreAuthenticationDetailsSource() );
    customPreAuthFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler( new CustomPreAuthSuccessHandler() );
    return customPreAuthFilter;
  }


  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                          AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {

    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests( request ->
                    request.anyRequest().authenticated() )
            .addFilter( customPreAuthFilter( authenticationManager ) )
            // permit being loaded into iframe
            .headers( headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable) )
            .build();

  }


}

from the filter
  @Override
  @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason="Direct access not permitted")
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String referer = httpRequest.getHeader( "Referer" );
    HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);
    if ( httpSession == null ) {
      log.debug( "no active session yet" );
      boolean isValidReferer = false;
      if ( referer != null ) {
        for (String validReferer : this.validReferers) {
          if (referer.startsWith(validReferer)) {
            isValidReferer = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if ( referer == null || !isValidReferer ) {
        throw new ServletException( "Direct access not permitted" );
      }
    }

    super.doFilter( request, response, chain );
  }

The entire project sample can be found at https://github.com/smaring/spring-pre-auth-filter
The use-case is that if the initial request contains an email param we will assume that the user was properly authenticated in the referer.  The app is loaded into an iframe.  If the refer is not valid the app throws the exception.
EDIT:
I tried adding
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

  @ExceptionHandler(ServletException.class)
  public String exception(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response,
                          Exception ex,
                          Model model) {
    model.addAttribute( "message", ex.getLocalizedMessage() );
    return "error";
  }

}

but it didn't seem to help.  The logs still get ...
2024-08-07T16:43:39.619-04:00 ERROR 1144375 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Direct access not permitted] with root cause

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Direct access not permitted
    at org.example.security.CustomPreAuthFilter.doFilter(CustomPreAuthFilter.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
...
2024-08-07T16:43:39.641-04:00 ERROR 1144375 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Direct access not permitted
    at org.example.security.CustomPreAuthFilter.doFilter(CustomPreAuthFilter.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
...
2024-08-07T16:43:39.644-04:00 ERROR 1144375 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing [ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]]

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Direct access not permitted
    at org.example.security.CustomPreAuthFilter.doFilter(CustomPreAuthFilter.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
...

ANOTHER EDIT:
I've created another filter to capture the exception and send it to the default resolver
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FilterChainExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
  private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
    }

  }
}

I've tried using ControllerAdvice
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex ) {
    log.info( "handling exception from filter chain" );
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    modelAndView.getModel().put( "message", ex.getLocalizedMessage() );
    return modelAndView;
  }
}

This results in
2024-08-07T19:12:49.437-04:00 DEBUG 1191696 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.example.security.CustomPreAuthFilter   : no active session yet
2024-08-07T19:12:49.439-04:00  WARN 1191696 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.s.FilterChainExceptionHandler        : Direct access not permitted
2024-08-07T19:12:49.470-04:00 DEBUG 1191696 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler org.example.controller.ExceptionController#handleException(Exception)
2024-08-07T19:12:49.471-04:00  INFO 1191696 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.controller.ExceptionController       : handling exception from filter chain
2024-08-07T19:12:49.482-04:00  WARN 1191696 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Direct access not permitted]

It stops there.  No view is presented back to the browser.
I've also tried a custom resolver
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FilterChainExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

  @Override
  public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    log.info( "handling exception from filter chain" );
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    modelAndView.addObject( "message", ex.getLocalizedMessage() );
    return modelAndView;
  }

}

updated the handler with
  @Autowired
  private FilterChainExceptionResolver resolver;

and registered in a WebMvcConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers( List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers ) {
    resolvers.add(0, new FilterChainExceptionResolver());
  }

}

The result of this is similar
2024-08-07T20:22:45.219-04:00 DEBUG 1214150 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.example.security.CustomPreAuthFilter   : no active session yet
2024-08-07T20:22:45.220-04:00  WARN 1214150 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.s.FilterChainExceptionHandler        : Direct access not permitted
2024-08-07T20:22:45.220-04:00  INFO 1214150 --- [Pre Auth Filter] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.s.FilterChainExceptionResolver       : handling exception from filter chain

It stops there with no view presented back to the browser.

I think my solution may be in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77635124/exception-not-throwed-to-global-api-error-handler and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring

A co-worker figured out the problem.  The OncePerRequestFilter was not able to continue the filterChain when an exception was thrown.  We just needed to direct it to do so in the catch block.
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

  }

